# Was "haut man in die Fresse"?

Tags: word-choice, idiom

> "Hau ihm eine in die Fresse!"

(Aus [50 dessins d'humour pour perfectionner votre allemand](http://www.amazon.fr/dessins-dhumour-perfectionner-votre-allemand/dp/2253059730/ref=cm_rdp_product), )

Eine was?

Ich hätte "**einen** (Faustschlag)" erwartet.

Comment: Wenn du "einen Faustschlag" erwartest, warum schlussfolgerst du dann nicht zu "eine Faust"? *Hau ihm eine (Faust) in die Fresse!*

Comment: Aus dem Bauch heraus würde ich den Ursprung in dem Bezug zu *Backpfeife* oder *Ohrfeige* vermuten.

Comment: @ Olaf: ich würde vorschlagen, dass du deinen Kommentar in eine Antwort umwandelst.

Comment: Üblicher als das würde ich "Hau ihm eine runter" erwarten...

Answer (score 3):

Der nur in der Umgangssprache verwendete Satz kann zu folgendem Satz erweitert werden:

> "Hau ihm eine X in die Fresse!"

wobei X für ein Wort steht, das weibliches Geschlecht haben muß (Wen oder was haue ich in die Fresse? Eine X). Somit kann X durch die folgenden, teilweise bereits in Kommentaren genannten Worte ersetzt werden:

- (die) Faust (die geschlossene Hand; der Schlag kommt eher von vorne oder von unten, dann "der Kinnhaken" genannt),
- (die) Hand (der Schlag kommt eher von der Seite, da Hand als offene Hand interpretiert wird; das wäre eine Ohrfeige oder Backpfeife (umgangssprachlich)).

Etwas anderes, wie etwa der Faustschlag oder ein Zahlwort, machen keinen Sinn. Da es für einen Schlag mit der offenen Hand einen eignen Begriff die Ohrfeige/die Backpfeife gibt, bleibt die Faust übrig.

Vollständig lautet der Satz also:

> "Hau ihm eine Faust in die Fresse",

wobei ohne Faust der Satz zur festen Redewendung wurde.

Answer (score 2):

Es geht bei dieser Aufforderung überhaupt nicht darum was gehaut wird. Da ist völlig nebensächlich und irrelevant. Wichtig ist wem wohin gehaut werden soll, nämlich "ihm in die Fresse", wobei die "Fresse" vor allem in Österreich je nach geographischer Region auch durch die Synonyme "Fotzn", "Goschn" oder "Pappn" ersetzt werden kann und der Satz nur äußerst selten in Hochdeutsch, sondern meist im lokalen Dialekt vorgetragen wird.

Auch bei ähnlichen Umschreibungen wie "Gleich gibt's was auf den Sender" oder "Hans hat von Tom eine aufs Dach bekommen" geht es nie darum was genau da auf den Sender gegeben werden soll oder was Tom aufs Dach bekommen hat.

Aus der Bedeutung dieser Phrasen geht hervor, dass es ein Schlag sein muss. Ob dieser Schlag mit der bloßen Hand oder durch einen Gegenstand verstärkt ausgeteilt wird, und ob die Hand offen oder zur Faust geballt ist wird in all diesen Formulierungen offen gelassen, weil es völlig egal ist.

Ich kenne die Phrase aus der Frage übrigens auch so:

> Hau ihm **eins** in die Fresse.

In diesem Fall wäre das gehaute Objekt also sächlich, was alle Versuche, aus diesem Ausdruck ein weibliches Objekt herzuleiten, fragwürdig erscheinen lässt. Die männliche Variante "Hau ihm *einen* in die Fresse" habe ich aber noch nie gehört.

Answer (score 1):

> Hau ihm eine

kann auch alleine stehen und ist ein fester Ausdruck. Er stammt (vermutlich) einfach vom Zahlwort, besagt also, dass der Empfänger der Schläge 1 bekommen soll und nicht 2 oder 3.

> in die Fresse

spezifiziert dann nur noch wohin der Schlag gehen soll.

Comment: Hm, da stimmt IMHO was nicht. Wenn der Ausdruck vom Zahlwort stammt, müsste es *Hau ihm eins* heißen, oder? In jedem Fall bliebe die Frage, wieso es sich um die weibliche Form handelt.

Comment: @ Olaf: ja, ich bin ganz deiner Meinung. Das Problem der weiblichen Form des Zahlwortes bleibt ungelöst.

Comment: Bemerkenswerterweise haut man zwar "eine auf/in die Fresse" aber man gibt "eins auf die Nuss" oder "(et)was aufs Maul". Zumindest was ich so kenne.

Comment: Gegen die Zahlentheorie spricht auch, dass man nie sagt "Hau ihm zwei (drei, ein halbes Dutzend, ...) in die Fresse.